# Add left margin to time in chat messages

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, design

I just saw this in a chat message and recoiled in horror:

[image]

Could the CSS of the `.timestamp` class get a `margin-left` of a few pixels?

Comment: I'm trying to remember why I didn't do that... I think there was a reason, but it's been a long time, I might just be wrong. If I don't remember it soon I'll add it.

Comment: Way in the beginning it was absolutely positioned, maybe that was why (the margin wouldn't have made a difference).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't want to be responsible for you recoiling in horror, so there you go:

[image: screenshot of a CSS file diff that shows margin-left: 10px; being added]

That's in the next build.